# Placing a number in a scale

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I've broken down everything that I can, I'm having trouble figuring out this calculation:

- Given I have a `MIN` number and a `MAX` number, with `MIN` < `MAX`
- I have a number `X`, where `MIN` <= `X` <= `MAX`
- Where `MIN` represents 0 on a scale
- And `MAX` represents 5 on a scale
- I want to calculate the, what I'm calling **scale number**, of `X` where 0 <= `X` <= 5

I know that if:

- `X` = `MIN`, the scale number would equal `0`
- `X` = `MAX` the scale number would equal `5`

But I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm not entirely sure what to tag this.

**EDIT**

My first attempts was:

Figure out the scale length say 0-5, where MIN = 0 and MAX = 5, so S = 5
Then figure out the steps, where (MAX-MIN)/(S-1), But that would really only be able to give me the ability to say if 1 <= X <= 2 OR 2 <= X <= 3 and so on.

It seems like I have to normalize the numbers of MIN and MAX to equal 0 and 5(scale size) respectively. Than figure out the calculation to put X between those 2 numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Will do

Comment: @Zac I'm trying to come up with an equation, using max and min as variables, so that when X is outside the bounds of min and max, i can recalculate everything that I need to

Comment: Are you familiar with [normalizing data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range)? Is that similar to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want to scale a variable $x$ with a minimum and maximum value to a variable $y$ with a minimum and maximum value, you are best describing the system in terms of Cartesian co-ordinates, with m being the slope or in this case scale factor which cancels out

$$\frac{ (y-y_{min})}{ (y_{max}-y_{min}) }=\frac{m(x-x_{min})}{m(x_{max}-x_{min})}=\frac{(x-x_{min})}{(x_{max}-x_{min})}$$

then by rearranging $y$ is easily calculated given $x$, $x_{min}$, $x_{max}$, $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$

$$y=(x-x_{min} ) \;\frac{ (y_{max}-y_{min}) }{(x_{max}-x_{min})}+y_{min}$$

(But is that the answer to the question you are asking, I'm not entirely sure, your prose is far from clear)

Answer (score 0):

If  you want find the  number $n$ that ''represents'' in the interval $[0,5]$ a given $x$ , in   a directly proportional way than you have:
$$
x:(Max-Min)=n:5
$$

find $n$ ...

Comment: What does `:` represent mathematically here?

Comment: @BrettSantore that would be ratios. Same as, $$\frac{x}{(Max-Min)} = \frac{n}{5}$$